# How to compare two depression recovery plans?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, paired-comparisons

I have this kind of data:

```
Recovery plan |  Depression test  |  Admission  |  Score
========================================================
Type-1        |  Test-A           |  Before     |  ?
Type-1        |  Test-A           |  After      |  ?
Type-1        |  Test-B           |  Before     |  ?
Type-1        |  Test-B           |  After      |  ?
Type-2        |  Test-A           |  Before     |  ?
Type-2        |  Test-A           |  After      |  ?
Type-2        |  Test-B           |  Before     |  ? 
Type-2        |  Test-B           |  After      |  ?
```

Depressed participants are receiving help either according to plan 1 or 2. They are tested with depression tests A and B. If a participant gets admitted to a hospital, the tests are repeated.

How could I show that the recovery plan 1 is better than the recovery plan 2?

At the moment, I am planning to run the tests

- Paired t-test for Plan=Type 1, Test=Test-A
- Paired t-test for Plan=Type 1, Test=Test-B
- Paired t-test for Plan=Type 2, Test=Test-A
- Paired t-test for Plan=Type 2, Test=Test-B

to show that the admission helps the participants. To compare the plans, I plan to run the tests

- Plan-1 improvement vs. Plan-2 improvement, Test-A
- Plan-1 improvement vs. Plan-2 improvement, Test-B

The number of tests seems high. Am I doing something wrong? Tests A and B are not comparable, so ANOVAs are out (?)

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts about the number of t-tests that would require being too high is well-founded; you would be dramatically increasing your experiment-wise Type I error rate.

I would run a 2x2 Mixed Multivariate Analysis of Variance (MANOVA). This would allow you to test the main effects of Recovery Plan (Type 1 v. Type 2), Admission (Before v. After), and their interaction, for both of your depression variables (Test A, and Test B) in one model. Though Depression Test A and B may be different in some ways, they clearly share some overlap in the construct they are assessing. However, if you are concerned about scaling differences, you might consider standardizing those two variables and then used the standardized version as your outcome variables.

If you're using SPSS, [this set of slides](http://core.ecu.edu/ofe/StatisticsResearch/SPSS%20Series%203%20repeated%20measure%20ANOVA%20and%20%20MANOVA%20PDF.pdf) (start on slide 34) should give you a good start on conducting/interpreting a Mixed MANOVA.